How to read query parameter in azure b2c login URL before authentication?
I am trying to read a query parameter (appName) from the Azure B2C login URL before authentication. I have two apps using Single Sign-On (SSO) with shared sessions, and I want to show the app name on the login page.
I tried adding the parameter using OpenIdConnectEvents.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider, and reading it with JavaScript, but the app name is not displaying on the login page.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
      builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C").Bind(options);
      options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();

      options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider += context =>
          {
            var appName = "LicensePortal";
            context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("appName", appName);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

This is my Javascript code to get appname
<title>Sign up or sign in</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getQueryParameter(name) {
            const urlParams = new 
              URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            return urlParams.get(name);
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            const appName = getQueryParameter('appName');
            if (appName) {
                document.getElementById('appNameDisplay').innerText = appName;
        }
        };
    </script>

